# Issues installing Elementary OS 6 using HP Intel Pavilon

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

#### Spec laptop

- Intel core I7 (hexa core) 2.6ghz
- Geforce GTX 1660 Ti
- Hp Pavilon
  [image]

I've been installing Elementary OS 6 using **nomodeset** and **pci=off**, It installed and then I installed the Nvidia driver or properties software required such an Nvidia driver. Once I finished and restart the computer, it doesn't work, it has a black screen but the volume is working so the desktop is there but w/o video.

I have to change the boot menu again to **nomodeset**to see something but I don't know what else I have to install.

Please help , sorry if I didn't give you more information, let me know what other data you need

#### Updates 03-OCt-2021

After install nvidia-460 My laptop screen is still black (actually has the hp logo all the time ) but I can connect a 2nd screen using HDMI and it works, not sure what the issue is , help please!

`nvidia-smi` output

```
Sun Oct  3 17:29:23 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8     4W /  N/A |    320MiB /  5944MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       887      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                136MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1408      G   gala                              120MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2085      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       60MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     74.97*+  60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

#### Update oct-3-2021 3:44 pm

I just figured it out that prime is the problem, if i used nvidia or nvidia on demand for prime nvidia config, the laptop screen doesn't work but if I used the intel model with modeset only work the laptop screen. At least, the NVIDIA prime recognized the screen but it's still black.. any help is received please!!

I test those:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212787/external-monitor-connected-via-hdmi-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-hd-nv

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105332/external-monitor-not-working-ubuntu-nvidia

https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system

https://github.com/UrbanVampire/missing-firmware-fix

Install nvidia 470 and it's working as 460 no changes

#### Update oct-7-2021

- I tried to install the intel and nvidia version for POP OS distro and I had the same result you could work with one screen or the other but not both at the same time. at this point, I think this is an issue with linux and I won't be able to fix it (at least with  knowledge)

:(

Comment: If you can get to a shell, can you [edit] your question to include the output of `nvidia-smi`? This might reveal which setting(s) need to be modified 

Comment: For sure, let me try to get that , right now

Comment: @matigo thanks for reply.  I just added more updates,. thanks